# How to find average of transactions every 15 min in Sql server for last 7 days?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This question might not be new in forums , but struggling to get the expected out put.
Please any body share the similar requirements if we face with solutions.

I would like to find average of total transactions for every 15 min.

```
  create table logger

  (starttime datetime,
  endtime datetime,
  response bit)

starttime                      endtime          response
2019-10-14 15:08:38.533 2019-10-14 15:08:38.533 0
2019-10-14 15:08:40.533 2019-10-14 15:08:42.563 0
2019-10-14 15:09:40.533 2019-10-14 15:10:43.563 0
2019-10-14 15:09:41.533 2019-10-14 15:10:43.563 1
```

expected result:

[image]

Below is the script i am using to generate number of seconds.
tried with below articles but no luck to achive the goal.

[Script](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=1341056964785354138#editor/target=post;postID=5797398234800649517;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,STARTTIME,ENDTIME) FROM logger
```

Comment: I am using Sql server 2012

Comment: Use CTE, build ranges list (from 00:00-00:15 till 23:45-00:00) and join it to your data table, then group and count.

Comment: could you please share some sample script please?

Answer (score 2):

Base template:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 0 num, 
                     @start_date rangestart, 
                     DATEADD(minute, @start_date, @duration) rangeend
              UNION ALL
              SELECT num + 1, 
                     DATEADD(minute, @start_date, @duration * (num + 1)), 
                     DATEADD(minute, @start_date, @duration * (num + 2)) 
              FROM cte 
              WHERE DATEADD(minute, @start_date, @duration * (num + 1)) < @enddate 
            )
SELECT ...
FROM datatable, cte
WHERE datatable.datetime >= cte.rangestart
  AND datatable.datetime < cte.rangeend
GROUP BY cte.num
```